# How to get nth element from a 10-tuple in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, tuples

I have to get nth element in a Haskell tuple. And the tuples are like this : 
(3,5,"String1","String2","String3","String4","String5","String6","String7","String8","String9","String10"). Can you give me an idea so that I can solve this problem?
Thanks.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

As you may or may not know fst and snd only work for 2-element tuples ie

```
fst' (a,b) = a
```

You have to write you own as far as I know

```
get5th (_,_,_,_,a,_,_,_,_,_) = a
```

As you can see you may want to define your own type.

Answer (score 48):

You could do it with pattern matching. Just like you can match against a two- or three-value tuple, you can match against a ten-value tuple.

```
let (_, _, _, _, _, _, _, _, _, x, _, _) = tuple in x
```

However, chances are you don't *want* to do that. If you're trying to get the nth value out of a tuple, you're almost definitely using the wrong type. In Haskell, tuples of different lengths are different *types*--they're fundamentally incompatible. Just like `Int` and `String` are different, `(Int, Int)` and `(Int, Int, Int)` are also completely different.

If you want a data type where you can get the nth element, you want a list: something like `[String]`. With lists, you can use the `!!` operator for indexing (which starts at 0), so you could just do:

```
myList !! 9
```

to get the 10th element.

Given your example, I suspect you want a type like `(Int, Int, [String])` rather than a gigantic tuple. This will let you have two numbers and any number of strings; you can get the strings by index using the `!!` operator as above.

Comment: Thank you very much for such a good answer. I have an input as a 10-tuple and I have to get the elements from it.  I want to learn if it is easy to divide the tuple to 2 different lists : first a list of 2 integers and a list of 8 strings?

Comment: @user1954132: To do that, you'd have to pattern match against the tuple anyhow. If you can't get the input as a different type, you'll have to pattern match against it at some point, which is going to be a bit awkward. You can get the values by replacing the `_` in my example with names--`_` in a pattern just means that you don't care about the value at that position.

Comment: It's not a good idea to suggest using `!!`, because it's partial, and it's even worse to suggest using a list for accessing an item by index. [Vector's `!?`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/vector/0.10.0.1/doc/html/Data-Vector.html#v:-33--63-) on the other hand is fine.

Comment: Yes if you want a structure for storing indexed data, List is not the right structure.  It is not meant for indexing and is more akin to a control flow structure.  Vector or Arrays are meant for this --- just like in every other language.

Comment: What if I want to handle vectors with different type, and call its element easily? .. Isn't there a cleaner way in Haskell?

Comment: @Student that's a deep question on its own, worth asking separately. (It's probably already addressed somewhere on SO.) Unsatisfyingly, the comment-length answer is that it depends on exactly what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 26):

You might like to use [the selection functions from the tuple package](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/tuple/0.2.0.1/doc/html/Data-Tuple-Select.html).

Answer (score 6):

If you only need to do this once per tuple, and you need all the elements at once, you can simply use

```
let (x, y, s1, s2, s3, s4, s5, s6, s7, s8) = someTuple
in ...
```

and use the values directly.

Answer (score 1):

I think you better use a record type, like:

```
data MyRec = MyRec {myrecfoo::Double, myrecbar::String, myrecbaz::String}
```

and then use the record accessors:

```
baz = myrecbaz rec
```

But if you want/need to stick with tuples and have less than 20 fields you can use [Control.Lens.Tuple](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens/docs/Control-Lens-Tuple.html)

Answer (score 0):

I have seen your question when i was searching a solution for the same problem. I have read the "!!" operator is a bad solution. I have thought a solution:

For example, if you have three elements for each tuple in your list you can do this:

```
nTuple :: [(a, a, a)] -> Integer -> Integer -> [a]
nTuple list group position = [ fst x | x <- (concat [ fst x | x <- (zip [(zip[t1, t2, t3][0..]) | (t1, t2, t3) <- list ] [0..]) , snd(x) == group ]) , snd(x) == position]
```

Now, some test cases:

```
*Main> nTuple [("l","m","n"),("o","p","q"),("r","s","t")] 2 1
["s"]

*Main> nTuple [("l","m","n"),("o","p","q"),("r","s","t")] 0 2
["n"]

*Main> nTuple [("l","m","n"),("o","p","q"),("r","s","t")] 100 2
[]

*Main> nTuple [("l","m","n"),("o","p","q"),("r","s","t")] 2 100
[]
```

Explication step by step of the above function:

1.Split elements and put an index:

```
[ zip[t1,t2,t3][0..] | (t1,t2,t3) <- [("l","m","n"),("o","p","q"),("r","s","t")]]

result: [[("l",0),("m",1),("n",2)],[("o",0),("p",1),("q",2)],[("r",0),("s",1),("t",2)]]
```

2.For each list put an index. Now we have groups and positions within each group.

```
zip [[("l",0),("m",1),("n",2)],[("o",0),("p",1),("q",2)],[("r",0),("s",1),("t",2)]] [0..]

result: [([("l",0),("m",1),("n",2)],0),([("o",0),("p",1),("q",2)],1),([("r",0),("s",1),("t",2)],2)]
```

3.We can select a group. For example the group number 1 (first group is the 0) with "snd(x)==1"

```
[ fst x | x <- [([("l",0),("m",1),("n",2)],0),([("o",0),("p",1),("q",2)],1),([("r",0),("s",1),("t",2)],2)] , snd(x) == 1 ]

result: [[("o",0),("p",1),("q",2)]]
```

4.We have a list of lists. Whe concatenate tuples in a single list of tuples

```
concat [[("o",0),("p",1),("q",2)]]

result: [("o",0),("p",1),("q",2)]
```

5.Finally, we get a element by index. In this example we get the 2nd element (first element is the "0" position)

```
[ fst x | x <- [("o",0),("p",1),("q",2)] , snd(x) == 2]

result ["q"]
```

Comment: What does this have to do with the question?

Comment: Does the user want to obtain an element after giving the position of that element?

Please, read my response slowly. I do not understand your negative vote.

My "nTuple" function does that user wants, I think.

:/

Comment: The question has to do with extracting an element from a single large tuple. Your answer has something to do with a list of tuples.

Comment: I tried to give a generic solution for one or more tuples. I'm new to Stackoverflaw. Next time I'll try to get to the point. Sorry.

Comment: It's perfectly fine to take a circuitous or extra-general approach. But you always need to come back around to show how it answers the question it solves the poser's problem. In this case, I don't think it does. Also, while it's great to work from the general to the specific, it's *also* important to work from the small to the large. I think any good solution for lists of tuples will be built from one for individual tuples. In fact, a solution for lists of tuples is probably *not* what you want if you know exactly how many tuples you have!

Answer (score 0):

say for example you have 4 directions, West East North and South, and you want to extract the value of each of those ( let's suppose that the tuple has the direction in this order W E N S)

```
Coord::(Int,Int,Int,Int)
Coord = (0,10,0,5)
```

if you try and extract the values  like this

```
let (W,E,N,S)= Coord
```

your compiler will scream at you, to counter that, you'll have to have getters for each of your values ( Yes individually)

```
getW (W,_,_,_) = W
getE (_,E,_,_) = E
getN (_,_,N,_) = N
getS (_,_,_,S) = S
```

and there you go !

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. I'm afraid this is not a useful answer though: **1.** it's unclear what you're actually explaining here and what it provides that the other answers don't contain already **2.** this is not legal Haskell code. Variables can't be uppercase.